# bind: data/named.run permission denied

Tags: linux, bind

I just installed Fedora 23 and bind-9.10 on it and the default installation does not run. I only created a zone file (which has ok-ed by the syntax check process), but this error is not related to any zone data I have created:

```
Jan 05 08:05:09 localhost.localdomain named[5786]: isc_file_isplainfile 'data/named.run' failed: permission denied
Jan 05 08:05:09 localhost.localdomain named[5786]: configuring logging: permission denied
Jan 05 08:05:09 localhost.localdomain named[5786]: loading configuration: permission denied
Jan 05 08:05:09 localhost.localdomain named[5786]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

these are the permissions on the following directories:

```
[root@localhost named]# ls -dl /var/named
drwxr-x---. 5 root named 4096 Jan  5 07:58 /var/named
[root@localhost named]# ls -dl /var/named/data
drwxrwx---. 2 named named 4096 Dec 16 12:15 /var/named/data
[root@localhost named]#
```

the directory /var/named/data is empty.

the strace shows the same error:

```
[pid  5794] open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 10
[pid  5794] fcntl(10, F_GETFL)          = 0x8800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  5794] fcntl(10, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE) = 0
[pid  5794] stat("data/named.run", 0x7f04aaf72630) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I expected that in the default installation there would not be such errors, like configuration of directory permissions. What is the problem here?

This is my /etc/named.conf file:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.14; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

    /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
    include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};


zone "supervisedchat.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/supervisedchat.dns";  # 10.128.0.0/16 subnet
};
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/supervisedchat.rev";  # 10.128.0.0/16 subnet
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

[root@localhost named]#
```

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?  "getenforce".  Is it denying anything?  grep deni /var/log/audit/audit.log   If so, have you restored the right selinux contexts to that directory structure?  restorecon -F -R -v /var/named

Comment: Also, did you use rpm -qa | grep ^bind | xargs rpm --setperms  to restore any permissions you may have changed?  Or something to that effect.

Comment: Is this a chrooted environment, by any chance? That would typically change your base path to `/var/named/chroot/var/named`.

Comment: @Aaron , no, I did not change any permissions, only created zone file and added it to named.conf . No "deni" appears in the audit.log either.

Comment: @AndrewB , no its not chrooted , or at least there is no "chroot" anywhere under /var/named/ directory

Comment: When I changed the owner of "/var/named/data" to "root" the named daemon started, but in the log file it complained that the "data/dynamic" and "data/slaves" has bad permissions. these directories have the same permissions as /var/named/data .

Comment: I tried rpm --setperms bind , but the error didn't go away

Comment: @Nulik change ownership to `chown -R named:named  /var/named` and restart service

Comment: Is named running as named user?  The start command is supposed to be "named -u named".

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem when setting up named in a container. You must run named as the correct user, which is `named` on Redhat/Fedora:

```
named -u named   # Possibly in the foreground using an additional -g
```

named drops all capabilities when starting (except some like the one to bind to low ports), so root loses its capability to read everyone's files, too. That means the "root user of the named process" can't read named's files anymore. That's why you have to run it as the user named using `-u named`.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named):

> Note: On Linux, named uses the kernel's capability mechanism to drop all root privileges except the ability to bind(2) to a privileged port and set process resource limits.

The default configuration on Fedora (or at least on the current Fedora 30) runs it using the correct option, however, when debugging you need to supply it manually, e.g. `named -u named -g`.

Comment: Thanks, this was not obvious at all. It's required when using named inside Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where named or bind is trying to create "data/named.run"?

Try

```
logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "/var/named/data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};
```

Without an absolute path, named is trying to access data/named.run in the cwd.

Comment: `directory       "/var/named";` defines the working dir

Comment: The default is "/var/named/", not "/var/named".  I wonder if that would make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

You're showing permissions for folder /var/named/data, but not its contents permissions. Is there perhaps your issue?

Comment: 1. its not a folder, its a directory. 2. I have said /var/named/data is empty

Comment: Try creating file /var/named/data/named.run and assigning ownership to the user who runs bind

Comment: I can easily chown /var/name/data to "root" or make it world writeable and it will work. The question is, what is the problem with the default configuration ??? and what are the correct permissions for /var/named/data ?